# How can I improve the performance of my flood-fill routine?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I'm implementing the four way flood fill in my application, pseudo code given below

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 2. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 3. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 4. Return
```

It's kind of slow and sometimes fills the call stack! And I'm really failed to calculate the complexity of this algorithm.

Can anyone suggest better algorithm to implement it, please?

Comment: @Manoj - what's your point? Although that question involves flood-filling, this isn't a dup. by any means. That question isn't about how to implement a floodfill - it's about how to build an optimal strategy for applying multiple floodfills to achieve a goal, which is quite different.

Comment: Just helping the guy. And I somehow feel this doesn't belong here. It belongs on SO.

Comment: @Prashant - what everyone is saying is that this question belongs on StackOverflow.  It will eventually get closed on this site.

Answer (score 4):

I cant help you with C# since I've only done this in Delphi, but I can help you with the call stack problem.  The trick is to not use a recursive algorithm.  Rather, use a stack based approach by maintaining a stack of points that need to be reviewed.

Basically, you add the 'start point' to the stack (and change its color).  Then while the stack is not empty, take the last point off the stack (ie, Pop it).  Do your comparisons for all 4 directions (left, right, up, down).  If any of the neighboring pixels need to flip to the new color, do the flip, and then add that neighboring point to the stack.  On your next loop through, there should be more points then on the stack.  Continue looping until the stack is empty.

Comment: This is a good point. The processor stack can be quite a limited resource - you cannot use the whole system memory (or anything remotely close) as CPU stack on most systems. A stack data structure managed on the heap can generally grow much bigger before causing problems.

Answer (score 4):

The current *state-of-the-art* floodfill algorithm (since 2006 or so) is based on finding the contour (the outermost boundary) of the connected component, converting the contour into horizontal pixel runs (and detecting and removing of internal holes from the connected component), then fill the pixel runs. The benefits are vastly reduced memory requirements (and/or stack level) as well as being faster (interior pixels are guaranteed to be read exactly once and written once). However the algorithm is not trivial. You'll need to read some research papers in order to implement it.

Comment: This is correct.  Horizontal or vertical runs are more efficient.  However, it is not too difficult once you reduce the bounded area to a set of 3 point polygons.  3 point polygons will not have holes and the runs for them can be further optimized.

Comment: @rwong: I am interested in this topic but didn't find a reference on this contour-tracing approach. If possible, do you have more pointers to guide me ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I'm not that knowledgeable enough to give suggestions. (Also, contour tracing is not the state-of-the-art anymore, because it doesn't run on GPUs.) My suggestion is to refer to [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/251459/620) instead, because the asker has already posted a very comprehensive list (along with the pitfalls) of the various approaches.

Comment: @rwong: Thanks for quickly answering. I am specifically interested in what you refer to in your answer; I understood that you read some article published around 2006; could it be "A Component-Labeling Algorithm Using Contour Tracing Technique by Chang & Chen" ? If yes, this is one of the best papers on connected components analysis, but not quite what I am looking for: I want to fill a blob from a given inside pixel, not find all blobs in the image. (Also in my context, GPU is irrelevant.)

Comment: Or could it be "a new and fast contour filling algorithm, Ren & Yang " ?

Comment: To be clear, contour tracing and filling from such does not produce the same output from the same input as described above - it is a solution for a different problem. Even though it is sometimes also called flood filling.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to reduce the number of items you typically need on the stack, by using larger items - horizontal lines rather than single pixels.

Each time you get a line from the stack/queue, scan the full length of this line one-pixel-north and one-pixel-south to form a number of additional horizontal lines to add to the stack. The eastmost and westmost of these lines may be able to grow east/west further than the bounds of the original line, so do this. Then add all these additional lines to the stack/queue.

The start point should also be extended to a line east and west before being added to the queue.

Coding will be a little trickier than a pixel-at-a-time flood-fill, but there are typically far fewer horizontal lines to worry about than pixels. There are perverse cases, though.

Comment: Thanks @Steve314. It sounds more optimal than what I did, however, I guess it going to be quite difficult code this.

Answer (score 1):

it think that what your dealing with is a graph and as i come to uderstand you should change the color of each node and replace it with another only if the target-color matches.

The complexity of this algorithm expressed in Big O is O( 4^n ) so i would recommend you try to implement a BFS algorithm, this way you might avoid leaving an unconneted node without changind and also avoid passing more than once on any vertice. That way you should be able to perfom in something like O( | E | + | V | ) where |E| is the number of edges and |V| is the number of vertices.

Here its a link to [wikipedia explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), and its quite simple so check this out!

PS: If you need a had with the algorithm i'd be more than happy to help you!

Comment: Shouldn't the complexity be O(n^2)? I thought that it was O(4^n) too, but being n the max size of the matrix, there is no way it could traverse more spaces in the matrix that there are.

Comment: Should the complexity have been O(4^n), few the flood filling engines on Earth would have finished their task on typical areas. F.i., 4^100 = 10^60. The complexity is just linear in terms of the number of pixels to fill, O(n) (or O(n²), depending on what n denotes.)

Comment: This is wrong. The complexity of basic flood fill is O(n) in the number of pixels visited. I assume you're referring to the fact that almost every pixel is tested four times, but doing four times as much work as necessary is still just O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing this routine, it fills 4 million pixels per second.

On an I7 from 2017, that's equivalent to 9 million flooded pixels per second, so a 1024x1024 pixel image can be processed in about 0.1 seconds,using 10-15MB memory:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hQ1wA4Sl4c&feature=youtu.be

http://unity3dmc.blogspot.com/2017/02/ultimate-3d-floodfill-scanline.html?m=1