# Maze program time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the actual time complexity for the maze problem here?

Is it O(4 ^ (n ^ 2 ) ) (because of branch ^ depth) or O(n ^ 2) (because like dfs in the worst case will traverse matrix). I did some search and getting these 2 types of answers. can anyone give the difference or example between these 2-time complexity achievable code? 
Is code2 is of Time complexity O(n ^ 2) and first one  O(4 ^ (n ^ 2 ) ) ? 
Is code 1 backtracking and code 2  dfs?

https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/backtracking-to-solve-a-rat-in-a-maze-c-java-pytho/

## code 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

//the maze problem
int maze[SIZE][SIZE] = {
    {0,1,0,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,0,1,0,1},
    {0,0,1,0,0},
    {1,0,0,1,0}
};

//matrix to store the solution
int solution[SIZE][SIZE];

//function to print the solution matrix
void printsolution()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",solution[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

//function to solve the maze
//using backtracking
int solvemaze(int r, int c)
{
    //if destination is reached, maze is solved
    //destination is the last cell(maze[SIZE-1][SIZE-1])
    if((r==SIZE-1) && (c==SIZE-1))
    {
        solution[r][c] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    //checking if we can visit in this cell or not
    //the indices of the cell must be in (0,SIZE-1)
    //and solution[r][c] == 0 is making sure that the cell is not already visited
    //maze[r][c] == 0 is making sure that the cell is not blocked
    if(r>=0 && c>=0 && r<SIZE && c<SIZE && solution[r][c] == 0 && maze[r][c] == 0)
    {
        //if safe to visit then visit the cell
        solution[r][c] = 1;
        //going down
        if(solvemaze(r+1, c))
            return 1;
        //going right
        if(solvemaze(r, c+1))
            return 1;
        //going up
        if(solvemaze(r-1, c))
            return 1;
        //going left
        if(solvemaze(r, c-1))
            return 1;
        //backtracking
        solution[r][c] = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;

}

int main()
{
    //making all elements of the solution matrix 0
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            solution[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    if (solvemaze(0,0))
        printsolution();
    else
        printf("No solution\n");
    return 0;
}
```

## code 2

changes

```
int visited[SIZE][SIZE];
int solvemaze(int r, int c)
{
    //if destination is reached, maze is solved
    //destination is the last cell(maze[SIZE-1][SIZE-1])
    if((r==SIZE-1) && (c==SIZE-1))
    {
        solution[r][c] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    //checking if we can visit in this cell or not
    //the indices of the cell must be in (0,SIZE-1)
    //and solution[r][c] == 0 is making sure that the cell is not already visited
    //maze[r][c] == 0 is making sure that the cell is not blocked
    if(r>=0 && c>=0 && r<SIZE && c<SIZE && visited[r][c] == 0 && maze[r][c] == 0)
    {
    visited[r][c] = 1;
        //if safe to visit then visit the cell
        solution[r][c] = 1;
        //going down
        if(solvemaze(r+1, c))
            return 1;
        //going right
        if(solvemaze(r, c+1))
            return 1;
        //going up
        if(solvemaze(r-1, c))
            return 1;
        //going left
        if(solvemaze(r, c-1))
            return 1;
        //backtracking
        solution[r][c] = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: From the look of it, I would say that the function you wrote has an exponential time complexity. You would have to use dynamic programming tecniques in order to acheive polynomial time complexity.

Comment: Why not a dijkstra ? It would be `O(n log n)`. (where `n` is `SIZE²` here)

Comment: Probable duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160614/flood-fill-four-way-algorithm-complexity

Comment: I've edited my question quite a bit, it should be a lot clearer now. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thought about it in detail, but here are my thoughts to start the discussion.

Consider the following maze:

```
0 0 0 0 .... 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 .... 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 .... 0 0 0 1 0
.                    .
.                    .
.                    .
0 0 0 0 .... 0 0 0 1 0
```

Your algorithm will go down first and then try out every possibility to fill the lower square. This is clearly exponential. So the algorithm is clearly not in O(n^2).

O(4^(n^2)) seems to be a valid upper bound, but i am sure, that this is not the lowest upper bound. For example, you cannot go backwards, so you have only 3 choices at every position.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.I've updated my question. can you have a look?