# given a matrix and some rules, what is the minimum number of days required to set all the bits of a binary matrix

Tags: c, algorithm

given a matrix and some rules, what is the minimum number of days required to set all the bits of a binary matrix
rules:

1. Only a cell having value '1', can set surrounding neighbor cells with distance of 1 unit, in 1 day.
2. The cell can set horizontally or vertically. diagonals are not to be considered as neighbors.

```
given a matrix(A) of rows(N), and columns(M)
A=[
     0 1 0 0 0 
     0 0 0 0 1
     0 0 0 1 0
     0 0 1 0 0
  ]

after 1 day
A=[
     1 1 1 0 1 
     0 1 0 1 1
     0 0 1 1 1
     0 1 1 1 0
  ]


after 2 day
A=[
     1 1 1 1 1 
     1 1 1 1 1
     0 1 1 1 1
     1 1 1 1 1
  ]

after 3 day
A=[
     1 1 1 1 1 
     1 1 1 1 1
     1 1 1 1 1
     1 1 1 1 1
  ]
```

minimum number of days required to set all cells is 3.

what can be the fastest algorithm?

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160614/flood-fill-four-way-algorithm-complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest algorithm has the complexity equal to O(M), where M -- the number of pixels, if you have matrix `NxN`, then your complexity is O(N*N).

The simplest algorithm would be to put every pixel that has value `1` in a list, then traverse the list, painting neighbours black and putting them to the list, then use that list to find the new neighbours to paint and add to the list. Obviously no pixel would be painted twice, so the algorithm is linear to the number of pixels.

Regarding the number of days, the worst case is `2*N`, when only one corner pixel is set to `1`.